# PHP str_replace separate image from text

Tags: php, str-replace

```
$item_content = '<p>'. str_replace('\n\n', '</p><p>', $item_content) .'</p>'; 

<?php
    $item_content = '<img class="attachment-frontpage-smallthumb wp-post-image" width="140" height="80" title="Screen shot 2013-10-25 at 11.55.11 AM" alt="Screen shot 2013-10-25 at 11.55.11 AM" src="http://media.gizmodo.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Screen-shot-2013-10-25-at-11.55.11-AM.png">
        How do you revive the Sh*t Girls Say meme that’s dead not only because we all grew tired of it, but because YouTube productivity assassins (aka movie makers) simply ran out of different types of people to make fun of? You reverse it and switch it into shit people would NEVER say. Like nerds thinking [...]
        <img width="1" height="1" border="0" src="http://gizmodo.feedsportal.com/c/34920/f/644110/s/32e94f6a/sc/1/mf.gif">
        <br clear="all">';
    ?>
```

I'm trying to seperate the text so that the text will get wrapped with a `<p>` tag but the `str_replace` I've gotten wraps my entire string including image with `<p>`

Answer (score 0):

What happends if you use:

```
$p_pos = strpos($item_content, '<p>');
$item_content = substr($item_content, 0, $p_pos) . '<p>'. str_replace('\n', '</p>', str_replace('\n', '<p>', substr($item_content, $p_pos)) .'</p>';
```

That might solve your problem.

Comment: It still just wraps the entire string

Comment: I've updated my answer now, give it a try. What it basically does is it searches for the `<p>` element in the string. Then it get the first part before that element and it places the rest behind it, the `<p>` and `</p>` elements are stripped with the `str_replace` method

Comment: Strange, I think I'm understanding your question wrong. I have to go sadly, I hope someone else is able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

That kind of `str_replace` will be of no use here. And you should know that your task is not well posed. Some minimal change in HTML markup or even type of space characters (newline or not) will render previously working solution incorrect.

If text content you are willing to wrap is *always* in a separate line and all other lines  starts with tag (like in your current sample), you can try to use logic like this:

```
function wrapTextLines( $content, $whichTag='p' ) {
    $output = '';
    foreach( explode("\n",$content) as $line ) {
        $line = trim($line);
        if( $line[0]!='<' )
            $output .= "<{$whichTag}>{$line}</{$whichTag}>\n";
        else
            $output .= "{$line}\n";
    }
    return $output;
}
```

([Here it is in PHPfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/h2v-tb6))

**Or** another try is this regex, that will transform given HTML code, wrapping every text node (text between tags, containing something besides spaces) into `<p>` tag.

```
$wrapped_content = preg_replace( 
    '#>\s*([^\s<][^<]+)<#ms', 
    '><p>$1</p><', 
    $item_content 
);
```

([Here it is in PHPfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/aj0-9m7))

**Or**, being more specific, will wrap every text node going after `<img>` tag.

```
$wrapped_content = preg_replace( 
    '#(<img[^>]+>)\s*([^\s<][^<]+)<#ims', 
    '$1<p>$2</p><', 
    $item_content 
);
```

([Here it is in PHPfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/8fw-xh1))

Comment: this works if my string has a line break in it. is there a way to detect if say `<img src="http://">Text is here`

Comment: Updated my answer to add two other variants